# How to sneak better?

Tags: dark-souls

It's certainly much more advantageous when you see the enemy first and not the other way around. Ring of Fog helps a great deal with that, but you still need to walk instead of running to stay hidden longer before enemy sees you. But what other tricks are there to it?

I've noticed how different armor pieces produce variable amount of noise while moving, but does it matter in terms of stealth?

Also, shooting arrows near enemies will distract most of them and they'll turn around to the source of sound (where the arrow or a spell hit) and they'll stand like that for several seconds, allowing to sneakily get behind them and score a backstab.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Slumbering Dragoncrest Ring](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/slumbering-dragoncrest-ring) or the sorcery [Hush](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/hush) to make no sound while moving, so you won't have to walk instead of running anymore. If you have no ring slot left for the Ring of Fog, you can alternatively use the [Hidden Body](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/hidden-body) sorcery as well. If you get detected and want to escape enemies, you could also try to use the [Chameleon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/chameleon) spell after running away to stop them from following you.

[This](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/606312-dark-souls/66275412) forum post also suggests that the weight of torso armor affects noise and detection by enemies. I remember that armor made a difference in Demon's Souls, but I am not sure how much it really affects noise in Dark Souls. It would make sense though that light armor is less noisy.

Generally, having both the Ring of Fog and the Slumbering Dragoncrest Ring equipped should make sneaking around much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The most defining factor in my opinion for losing the chance of a backstab is that there seems to be a certain distance that you have to be at before you can backstab... shortly after this point the enemy is automatically alerted to your presence and then they turn round and attack, using the rings and spells and wearing as lighter footwear as possible (other armour does not have any affect I've been told) as stated in other answers, while trying to find that certain sweet point where your backstab can reach them but they aren't alerted is the best way to scoring a backstab. Also the angle at which you approach is very defining of the backstab success as the line of sight is very exadurated on the enemy AI. Make sure you are as directly behind the enemy as possible. Positioning is as important as how quickly or slowly you walk.